# Как по RSA зашифровать строку используя при этом ключ из сертификата? RSA, C#, *.CER

Tags: c#, rsa, x509certificate

Нужно извлечь ключ из сертификата `.cer` и с помощью него зашифровать используя `RSA`.
Так же можно сделать? Я правильно понял, что от меня хотят?

> **Формирование подписи запроса**
> Для формирования ключей используется протокол `X.509`.
> Для формирования подписи исходящего запроса необходимо:
>
> 1)Используемый при формировании ЭЦП алгоритм `RSA + SHA1`  `http://www.w3.org/PICS/DSig/RSA-SHA1_1_0.html`
> 2)Подписывается содержимое исходящего сообщения заключенное между тегами `<rsb_ns:request>` и  `</rsb_ns:request>`  исключая сами теги.
> 3)Полученное значение подписи помещается в тег `sig` в формате `HEX`.

Так вот, извлечь публичный ключ в виде шестнадцатеричной строки я смог
И `RSA` в `SHA1` - тоже знаю как.
Вопрос в том, как зашифровать(`RSA`) строку используя при этом ключ из сертификата?

```
string fileName = @"C:\Users\***\*.cer";
X509Certificate cert = new X509Certificate(File.ReadAllBytes(fileName));
if (cert == null) {MessageBox.Show("не удалось загрузить сертификат");}
string CertKey = cert.GetPublicKeyString();
string StrForEncode = Pars("<request>", xml_text, "</request>");
RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
RSA.FromXmlString(CertKey);
byte[] ByteForEncode = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetBytes(StrForEncode);
byte[] BufferSig = RSA.Encrypt(ByteForEncode, false);
byte[] StrSig = RSA.SignData(BufferSig, new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider());
string StrSigOut = BitConverter.ToString(StrSig);//.Replace("-", "");
xml_text = xml_text + "<rsb_ns:sig>" + StrSigOut + "</rsb_ns:sig>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не сможете подписать ничего имея только публичный ключ. Для генерации подписи нужен приватный ключ. Ваш код слишком сложный, можно сделать вот так:

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2(...);
var rsa = cert.PublicKey.Key as RSACryptoServiceProvider;
// ...
var enc = rsa.Encrypt(bytes, ...);
// ...
var signature = rsa.SignData(enc, "SHA1"); // здесь будет ошибка, потому что нет приватного ключа
```

Comment: Приватный ключ идет в сертификате? или его нужно запросить у админов сервера? и когда он будет, куда его "пихать"?

Comment: `*.cer` содержит только сертификат без приватных ключей. Есть другие форматы файлов (например `*.pfx` или `*.p12`), в них предусмотрена возможность для помещения приватных ключей. А так приватный ключ только у того, кто выдал сертификат.

Comment: Электронно-Цифровая Подпись (далее – ЭЦП)
Ассиметричные ключи создаются каждой из сторон самостоятельно. Затем выполняется обмен открытыми ключами для проверки подписи запроса. Запросы и ответы подписываются секретным ключом. Корректность подписи проверяется принимающей стороной открытым ключом.             Изначально сертификат был в формате `*.crt`

Comment: `*.crt` тоже самое что и `*.cer`. Вот, все правильно, никто не должен никому пересылать приватные ключи. Если 3-я сторона требует от вас подписи, вы должны сами генерировать сертификат, и передавать его третьей стороне (разумеется без приватного ключа). Приватный ключ остается только у вас.

Comment: т.е. нужно создать свой сертификат и с помощью него подписать содержимое тела запроса. Потом открытый ключ сообщить им?

Comment: Да, это правильный подход